# Blank page when deploying Quasar app to Firebase

Tags: firebase, vue.js, quasar-framework

I'm using Quasar `"^1.14.1"`, and I'm trying to deploy to Firebase. I'm building first with `quasar build -m spa`, and the deployment is successful. However the resulting page is blank.

This is my `firebase.json`:

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    "headers": [{
        "source": "/**",
        "headers": [{
          "key": "Cache-Control",
          "value": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        }]
      },
      {
        "source": "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|webp|js|css|eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff|woff2|font.css)",
        "headers": [{
          "key": "Cache-Control",
          "value": "max-age=604800"
        }]
      }
    ],
    "site": "mysitename",
    "public": "dist/spa",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [{
      "source": "**",
      "destination": "/dist/spa/index.html"
    }]
  }
}
```

I've also tried changing the destination to `"/index.html"`. No luck. I'm not sure what else to do. There are no errors in build or deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I'm using Firebase and `dotenv`, and I forgot to include my Firebase credentials in `.env.prod`.